# When pressing enter inside TextView, click button?

Tags: android

I have a text view (and possibly 1 or 2 Spinners after it) and a Button. When a user presses the enter key (soft or hard keyboard), I want to Click the **Search** button, which is next.

Is it only possible to do this by overriding the onKey event of the TextView and when Enter is pressed, performClick() the Button?

I can't find much information from Google, but i could be searching for the wrong term.

Cheers,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is only possible by overriding the onKey event.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just perform the action that the button click fires directly from the onClick-method on the TextField?

Comment: Yep, i'm an idiot. Thanks for that :) Actually, that doesn't work. That'll just fire the event every time i click on the search box. It should only happen when ENTER/RETURN is hit.